# Refreshing DIV via Jquery Load and Inside the page JavaScript is not working

Tags: jquery, load

I want to refresh the display div every some interval, and inside the page i hold some javascript to load from php file. But after refresh the inner page

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#load_0').load('image.php?id=1');
});
```

is not loading the content of image.php

Inner load not loading the content of image.php. After refresh it vanish. On first page load its displaying the content, later after page refresh its not displaying.

```html
<script>
  setInterval(function() {
    $('#display').load(location.href + " #display");
  }, 9000);
</script>
<div id="display">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#load_0').load('image.php?id=1');
    });
  </script>
  <a href="#" id="load_0"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Please put all relevant code in the question. I've edited for you in this case

Comment: load will not trigger the second ajax-ed script tag

Comment: and why do you need to load scripts?

Comment: Can you give suggestions how to make it work on alternative way. how to accomplish. I will give a try and keep you update

Comment: Actaully Image.php hold php code and display output based upon the id value

Comment: @madalinivascu its Working. Thanks

Comment: @Matrix glad to have helped

Answer (score 0):

Remove the first load, set the timeout to the second load

```
<div id="display">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      setInterval(function() {
         $('#load_0').load('image.php?id=1');
      }, 9000);
    });
  </script>
  <a href="#" id="load_0"></a>
</div>
```